# during theme installation im getting error

Tags: magento2, theme

during theme installation, I'm getting this error:

```
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalog':
[ERROR] Magento\Framework\Setup\Exception: Unable to apply patch Magento\InventoryCatalog\Setup\Patch\Schema\CreateLegacyStockStatusView for module Magento_InventoryCatalog. Original exception message: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'inventory_stock_1' already exists, query was: CREATE
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
VIEW inventory_stock_1
AS
SELECT
DISTINCT 
legacy_stock_status.product_id,
legacy_stock_status.website_id,
legacy_stock_status.stock_id,
legacy_stock_status.qty quantity,
legacy_stock_status.stock_status is_salable,
product.sku
FROM cataloginventory_stock_status legacy_stock_status
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity product
ON legacy_stock_status.product_id = product.entity_id; in /home/X/public_html/demo2/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Patch/PatchApplier.php:232
```

Stack trace

how can i solve this error in order to keep the installation process?

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue. I just made a backup of the `inventory_stock_1` table (a full backup is a good idea if this is a live site), then deleted it from the database.  This allowed the `setup: upgrade` script to complete.

Answer (score 0):

1. pls delete your view "inventory_stock_1" in database.
2. pls check your mysql username when import database and username when running setup theme. It should same.

Answer (score -1):

**Solved** For Magento 2.4.1 and above

Open File
MAGENTO_ROOT\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php

Search for **validateURLScheme** function and Replace by

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
{
  $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
  $url = parse_url($filename);
  //if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) ) {
  if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```